# How to Enable Source.Queue Backpressure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using [host-level API with a queue](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html).

```
  private val (queueSource, connectionPool) = Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](queueSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).async
    .viaMat(poolFlow)(Keep.both)
    .toMat(
      Sink.foreach({
        case ((Success(resp), p)) =>
          p.success(resp)
        case ((Failure(e), p)) => p.failure(e)
      })
    )(Keep.left)
    .run()
```

I have a lot of request racing for connections in the connection pool but I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have to wait for previous offer to be resolved to send another request
    at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1.akka$stream$impl$QueueSource$$anon$$bufferElem(QueueSource.scala:84)
    at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(QueueSource.scala:94)
    at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(QueueSource.scala:91)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.runAsyncInput(GraphInterpreter.scala:447)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:464)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:559)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:741)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:756)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:666)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I tried adding .async but back pressure still does not kick in. What does the error above mean and how to go about investigating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are already constructing a `Source` with the `Source.queue` object method so I don't think it is possible to directly apply back pressure to whatever functionality is calling `queue.offer`.   However, your problem can likely be solved in a different way.

**Different `OverflowStrategy`**

You could change the strategy to something like `OverflowStrategy.dropHead` or `OverflowStrategy.dropTail`.  If your `queueSize` is large enough compared to the rate of `queue.offer` invocations then this will probably suite your needs.

Comment: I can't afford to lose messages. Whats the point of backpressure strategy if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Rabzu I don't know of an example using the back pressure strategy with Source.queue.  If backpressure is that important to you then why use `Source.queue` in the first place?

Comment: whats the alternative?

Comment: I have a service for which I want to create a clients using akka-http. I'm creating a thread pool and which backpressures requests from materialised akka-http client streams. The docs clearly say that  host-level API with a queue [guards itself a) by applying backpressure to all request streams connected to the cached pool](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-with-a-queue) by applying backpressure to all request streams connected to the cached pool ).

Comment: Are you  asking me to use [host-level API in a streaming fashion](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-with-a-queue)?

Comment: @Rabzu Continue reading the example from your link, specifically the code that deals directly with the queue.  (1) They don't use `OverflowStrategy.backpressure`, instead they use ` Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](QueueSize, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)` .  (2)  They explicitly handle the case when the queue is full `Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Queue overflowed. Try again later."))` which is something you said you don't want to do: "I can't afford to lose messages."

Comment: ok, but as an alternative, should I use streamed method and if so, can the Source(List(request)) be replaced with ["anti pattern" Source.single(request)](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#examples) ?

Comment: @Rabzu I recommend another stack question.  I don't know exactly what you're looking for and I can't answer with sufficient detail in an answer comments...

Comment: I don't agree with you or your arguments. Documentation clearly states that backpressure is one of the strategies. When testing sometimes it works but in production it does not. So maybe it has something to do with threads. It cannot backpressure other threads

Comment: Thank you. I did post this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761994/how-to-create-akka-http-client-with-backpressure-overflow-strategy