# How do I get Akka HTTP to backpressure using connection pooling?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm running Akka Streams Typed 2.6.9 with Akka HTTP 10.1.12 in a service running in AWS ECS and I'm getting the error message "Exceeded configured max-open-requests value of 32" in my streaming application.  I've looked for answers and must have read [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/pool-overflow.html) about a dozen times now.

The application streams from an AWS SQS queue and uses this information to query a REST service.
The application is streaming "all the way through."  According to the documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html), the `Http().superPool()` implementation should backpressure.  If so, why am I filling up max-open-requests?  Shouldn't it backpressure the connection to the queue and not overload the pool?

I've tried throttling the requests, changing all `mapAsync()` calls to one thread, and even throttling from the queue, but the pool eventually fills up, however slowly.  What am I doing wrong?

Code is below...

```
object ExampleActor {
  object Start extends Protocol

  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  def buildAwsSqsClient(actorSystem: ActorSystem[Nothing]): SqsAsyncClient = {
    val awsCredentialsProvider = DefaultCredentialsProvider.create()
    val awsSqsClientBuilder = SqsAsyncClient
      .builder()
      .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
      .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
      .httpClient(AkkaHttpClient.builder().withActorSystem(actorSystem.classicSystem).build())
    // Possibility to configure the retry policy
    // see https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/aws-shared-configuration.html
    // .overrideConfiguration(...)

    if(System.getProperty("localstack", "false").equals("true")) {
      println("****Enabling localstack resource")
      awsSqsClientBuilder.endpointOverride(new URI("http://localhost:4566"))
    }

    implicit val awsSqsClient = awsSqsClientBuilder.build()

    actorSystem.classicSystem.registerOnTermination(awsSqsClient.close())

    awsSqsClient
  }

  def apply(): Behavior[Protocol] =
    Behaviors.setup { ctx: ActorContext[Protocol] =>
      def process(): Behavior[Protocol] =
        Behaviors.receiveMessage {
          case Start =>
            println("Start up")
            Behaviors.same[Protocol]
        }

      process()
    }

  def setupStream(context: ActorContext[Protocol])(implicit sqsClient: SqsAsyncClient, ex: ExecutionContext) = {
    val deleteSink = Flow[Message]
      .map(MessageAction.delete)
      .log("Mapping to delete action for getting rid of message from queue")
      .to(SqsAckSink("libraryPublish", SqsAckSettings.create()))

    val fromWebService = SqsSource(
      "libraryPublish",
      SqsSourceSettings.create()
        .withWaitTime(500.milliseconds)
    )
      .alsoTo(deleteSink)
      .map(_.body())

    val endingSink = Flow[BookCommand]
      .map(group => SendMessageRequest.builder().messageBody(group.toJson.toString).build())
      .log("Building message to SQS")
      .to(SqsPublishSink.messageSink("libraryPublishPost"))

    Flow[String]
      .map(runGroupId => retrieveLibrary(runGroupId))
      .via(queryBooks(context))
  }

  def queryBooks(context: ActorContext[Protocol]) = {
    Flow[Library]
      .map(library => {
        LibraryQuery(
          library.id,
          library.books.map(book =>
            AuthorIndex(
              book.author.lastName,
              library.tags match {
                case Subject(tagName) =>
                  DeweySearch.createSearch(tagName)
                case Character(tagName) =>
                  CharacterSearch(tagName)
                case Publisher(tagName) =>
                  PublisherSearch("publisher:" + tagName)
              }
            )
          )
        )
      })
      .mapAsync(4)(libraryQuery => {
          val seq = Source.single(libraryQuery)
            .mapConcat(_.bookQueries)
            .via(runBookQueries(context))
            .runWith(Sink.seq)

          LibraryAnswer(libraryQuery.id, seq)
        }
      )
      .map(libraryAnswer => insertIntoDb(libraryAnswer))
      .runWith(Sink.last)
  }

  def runBookQueries(context: ActorContext[Protocol]) = {
    implicit val ec = context.executionContext
    implicit val sys = context.system.classicSystem

    val httpFlow: Flow[(HttpRequest, BookQuery), (Try[HttpResponse], BookQuery), NotUsed] =
      Http().superPool[BookQuery]()

    val retryFlow: Flow[(HttpRequest, BookQuery), (Try[HttpResponse], BookQuery), NotUsed] = {
      RetryFlow.withBackoff(minBackoff = 10.millis, maxBackoff = 5.seconds, randomFactor = 0d, maxRetries = 3, httpFlow)(
        decideRetry = { (request, response) =>
          if(response._1.isFailure || response._1.get.status.isFailure) {
            logger.debug("Retrying answer query from {} response", response._1.get.status)
            response._1.get.discardEntityBytes()
            Some(request)
          } else {
            logger.debug("Request went through...")
            None
          }
        }
      )
    }

    Flow[BookQuery]
      .mapAsync(4)((query: BookQuery) => {
        //Cached token getter is a function that gets an API token for the book service
        CachedTokenGetter.getToken(context).map(token =>
          (
            Post("https://my.example.service")
              .withEntity(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, query.toJson.toString))
              .withHeaders(Authorization(OAuth2BearerToken(token.access_token))),
            query
          ))
      })
      .via(retryFlow)
      .flatMapConcat(pair => {
        getBookResponseFromPair(pair).map(answer => (pair._2, answer))
      })
      .map(pair => BookQueryAndAnswer(pair._1, pair._2))
  }

  def getBookResponseFromPair(pair: (Try[HttpResponse], BookQuery)): Source[BookAnswer, Any] = {
    pair._1.get.entity.dataBytes
      .via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(Int.MaxValue))
      .mapAsync(10)(bytes => Unmarshal(bytes).to[BookQueryResponse])
      .mapConcat(_.titles)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections` as the documentation link says?

Comment: I have.  I can increase it, but eventually it will run out.  For example, if I set it to 100, it just takes longer to crash.

Comment: You can also take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246795/2212849) to avoid `Exceeded configured max-open-requests` errors by using `Source.queue` with backpressure strategy.